# SQL XML - Create a XML file from SQL Server for an invoice including invoice positions in one XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I create my xml file in this way (I do not show all output fields because there are very many fields):

```
DECLARE @ID_Rechnung int = 8;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES  (
                        'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2' as ext,
                        'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2' as cbc,
                        'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' as cac,
                        'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#' as xades,
                        'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi,
                        'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' as ds
                    )    
SELECT
    @XMLData = xmldat.xmldataCol 
FROM
(
    SELECT
        (

        SELECT
            -- HIER XML Daten generieren
            ''                                          AS 'ext:UBLExtensions',
            ''                                          AS 'ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension',
            ''                                          AS 'ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent',
            '2.1'                                       AS 'cbc:UBLVersionID',
            'TR1.2'                                     AS 'cbc:CustomizationID',
            ''                                          AS 'cbc:ProfileID',
            Rechnungen.Nummer                           AS 'cbc:ID',
            'false'                                     AS 'cbc:CopyIndicator',
            ''                                          AS 'cbc:UUID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.Datum AS Date)              AS 'cbc:IssueDate'      
            
        FROM 
            rechnungen  
        WHERE 
            rechnungen.id = @ID_Rechnung


        FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Invoice') 
    ) AS xmldataCol
```

This works fine - i get the following XML:

```
<Invoice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent />
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID />
  <cbc:ID>R200001</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
  <cbc:UUID />
  <cbc:IssueDate>2020-06-29</cbc:IssueDate>
</Invoice>
```

But now i need the invoice positions in the same file.

This SQL should be included in the first one and the date should be as invoice line in the xml file:

```
SELECT
  Rechnungpos.ID                        AS 'cac:InvoiceLine/cbc:ID',
  Rechnungpos.Anzahl                    AS 'cac:InvoiceLine/cbc:InvoicedQuantity'
FROM
  RechnungPos 
WHERE
  RechnungPos.id_Rechnung = @ID_Rechnung
```

The output should be this:

```
<Invoice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent />
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID />
  <cbc:ID>R200001</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
  <cbc:UUID />
  <cbc:IssueDate>2020-06-29</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1<(cbc:>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>3</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>5<(cbc:>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>9<(cbc:>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>2</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Here is the Code to generate Test Data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rechnungen](
    [id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [Nummer] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Datum] [datetime] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Rechnungen (id, Nummer, Datum) VALUES (8, 'R200001', '29.06.2020')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].Rechnungpos(
    [id] [int]  NOT NULL,
    [id_Rechnung] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Anzahl] [float] NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO RechnungPos (id, id_Rechnung, Anzahl) VALUES (1, 8, 3) 
INSERT INTO RechnungPos (id, id_Rechnung, Anzahl) VALUES (5, 8, 1) 
INSERT INTO RechnungPos (id, id_Rechnung, Anzahl) VALUES (9, 8, 2)
```

it has to run on different versions - my version is SQL Server 2019

How can i do that?

Thanks for help, Thomas.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Thomas, (1) and (4) from my previous comment are still missing. Please provide.

Comment: Thanks for answering - i now make 1 and 4 - Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it.

The only complexity is how to handle a child table and specially namespaces in the output XML. That's why XQuery and its FLWOR expression are in use.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @Rechnungen TABLE (id int , Nummer nvarchar(20), Datum datetime);
INSERT INTO @Rechnungen (id, Nummer, Datum) VALUES 
(8, 'R200001', '2020-06-29');

DECLARE @Rechnungpos TABLE (id int, id_Rechnung int, Anzahl float);
INSERT INTO @RechnungPos (id, id_Rechnung, Anzahl) VALUES 
(1, 8, 3),
(5, 8, 1), 
(9, 8, 2);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @ID_Rechnung int = 8;

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2' as ext
    , 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2' as cbc
    , 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' as cac
    , 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#' as xades
    , 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
    , 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' as ds)
SELECT (
SELECT '2.1'               AS [cbc:UBLVersionID],
    'TR1.2'                AS [cbc:CustomizationID],
    ''                     AS [cbc:ProfileID],
    p.Nummer               AS [cbc:ID],
    'false'                AS [cbc:CopyIndicator],
    ''                     AS [cbc:UUID],
    CAST(p.Datum AS Date)  AS [cbc:IssueDate],
    (
        SELECT c.id AS [cbc:ID]
            , CAST(c.Anzahl AS INT) AS [cbc:InvoicedQuantity] 
        FROM @Rechnungpos AS c INNER JOIN 
            @Rechnungen AS p ON p.id = c.id_Rechnung
        FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
    )
FROM @Rechnungen AS p
WHERE p.id = @ID_Rechnung
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Invoice')
).query('<Invoice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
<ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
        <ext:ExtensionContent/>
    </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
{
   for $x in /Invoice/*[local-name()!="root"]
   return $x,
     for $x in /Invoice/root/r
     return <cac:InvoiceLine>{$x/*}</cac:InvoiceLine>
}
</Invoice>');
```

**Output**

```
<Invoice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
  <ext:UBLExtensions>
    <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent />
    </ext:UBLExtension>
  </ext:UBLExtensions>
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID />
  <cbc:ID>R200001</cbc:ID>
  <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
  <cbc:UUID />
  <cbc:IssueDate>2020-06-29</cbc:IssueDate>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>3</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>5</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
  <cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>9</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity>2</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
  </cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution - it works fine with the test data.
But if i try it with all fields from Rechnungen in the xm that i need, then i get an error message: Methods for nvarchar (max) cannot be called. (i translated from german in english) and the .query command was marked

Comment: I found the solution - i put all the selected data in a variable @XMLData from type XML
After that id do: ```SELECT @XMLData.query```

Comment: @Thomas, glad to hear that you found your complete solution, though it seems over-complicated. Please connect with me on LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Yitzhak Khabinsky for help - heres the complete solution:

```
DECLARE @ID_Rechnung int = 8,
    @XMLData xml;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2' as ext
    , 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2' as cbc
    , 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2' as cac
    , 'http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#' as xades
    , 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as xsi
    , 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#' as ds)
SELECT
    @XMLData = xmldat.xmldataCol 
FROM
(
SELECT (
       SELECT
            -- HIER XML Daten generieren
            ''                                          AS 'ext:UBLExtensions',
            ''                                          AS 'ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension',
            ''                                          AS 'ext:UBLExtensions/ext:UBLExtension/ext:ExtensionContent',
            '2.1'                                       AS 'cbc:UBLVersionID',
            'TR1.2'                                     AS 'cbc:CustomizationID',
            ''                                          AS 'cbc:ProfileID',
            Rechnungen.Nummer                           AS 'cbc:ID',
            'false'                                     AS 'cbc:CopyIndicator',
            ''                                          AS 'cbc:UUID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.Datum AS Date)              AS 'cbc:IssueDate',
            ''                                          AS 'cbc:InvoiceTypeCode',
            Rechnungen.Bemerkung1                       AS 'cbc:Note',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cbc:TaxCurrencyCode',
            Rechnungen.Auftrag                          AS 'cac:OrderReference/cbc:ID',
            -- Verkaüfer
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cbc:EndpointID',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cbc:StreetName',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cbc:CityName',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cbc:PostalZone',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cac:Country/cbc:IdentificationCode',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyTaxScheme/cbc:CompanyId',
            'VAT'                                       AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyTaxScheme/cac:TaxScheme/cbc:ID',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:RegistrationName',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:CompanyID',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:CompanyLegalForm',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:Contact/cbc:Name',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:Contact/cbc:Telephone',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:Contact/cbc:ElectronicMail',
            -- Käufer
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cbc:EndpointID',
            Rechnungen.DebKreNr                         AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID',
            Rechnungen.DebBez01 + ' ' + DebBez02        AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name',
            Rechnungen.DebStrasse                       AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cbc:StreetName',
            Rechnungen.DebOrt                           AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cbc:CityName',
            Rechnungen.DebPLZ                           AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cbc:PostalZone',
            Rechnungen.DebLandKFZ                       AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PostalAddress/cac:Country/cbc:IdentificationCode',
            Rechnungen.DebUMSTID                        AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyTaxScheme/cbc:CompanyID',
            'VAT'                                       AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyTaxScheme/cac:TaxScheme/cbc:ID',
            Rechnungen.DebBez01 + ' ' + DebBez02        AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:RegistrationName',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:Contact/cbc:Name',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:Contact/cbc:Telephone',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:Contact/cbc:ElectronicMail',
            -- Kontoverbindung Verkäufer
            ''                                          AS 'cac:PaymentMeans/cbc:PaymentMeansCode',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:PaymentMeans/cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:ID',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:PaymentMeans/cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:Name',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:PaymentMeans/cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cac:FinancialInstitutionBranch/cbc:ID',
            --''                                            AS 'cac:PaymentTerms/cbc:Note',
            -- Steuern
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cbc_TaxAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragMWST AS nvarchar(15)) AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cbc_TaxAmount',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cbc:TaxableAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragNetto AS nvarchar(15))AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cbc:TaxableAmount',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cbc:TaxAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragMWST  AS nvarchar(15))AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cbc:TaxAmount',
            ''                                          AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cac:TaxCategory/cbc:ID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.MWST AS nvarchar(2))        AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cac:TaxCategory/cbc:Percent',
            'VAT'                                       AS 'cac:TaxTotal/cac:Taxubtotal/cac:TaxCategory/cac:TaxScheme/cbc:ID',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:LineExtensionAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragNetto AS nvarchar(15))AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:LineExtensionAmount',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragNetto AS nvarchar(15))AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragBrutto AS nvarchar(15))AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount',
            @Waehrung                                   AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:PayableAmount/@currencyID',
            CAST(Rechnungen.BetragBrutto AS nvarchar(15))AS 'cac:LegalMonetaryTotal/cbc:PayableAmount',

    (
        SELECT Rechnungpos.id AS [cbc:ID]
            , CAST(Rechnungpos.Anzahl AS INT) AS [cbc:InvoicedQuantity] 
        FROM Rechnungpos WHERE RechnungPos.id_Rechnung = @id_Rechnung
        FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
    )
FROM Rechnungen 
WHERE Rechnungen.id = @ID_Rechnung
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Invoice')

) AS xmldataCol
) AS xmldat;

SELECT @XMLData
.query('<Invoice xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#"
         xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
         xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
         xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2">
{
   for $x in /Invoice/*[local-name()!="root"]
   return $x,
     for $x in /Invoice/root/r
     return <cac:InvoiceLine>{$x/*}</cac:InvoiceLine>
}
</Invoice>');
```