# xmlSample - The file is not a valid xml : The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed. SQL Xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

According to a xml Validator my xml is not valid.

I use a stored procedure that is called in some code to create the xml.
My code for the SP is as follows (Tried to use the code in [SQL XML - Create a XML file from SQL Server for an invoice including invoice positions in one XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555229/sql-xml-create-a-xml-file-from-sql-server-for-an-invoice-including-invoice-pos)). The output I get seems to look ok and not sure where the issue is coming from. The basic idea is to get data from Table InvoiceHeader and all the corresponding data in table InvoiceLines and output to a xml file on a file location per line in the InvoiceHeader table:

```
USE [INTELLECTION]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[XML_OUTVaribale]    Script Date: 2021/08/31 2:50:11 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XML_OUTVaribale]  @DOCID99 int/*5. Stored Procedure: Field Interpretation Stats (both HEADER and LINE fields) */
AS
BEGIN
--HEADER level field script
/* >> 5.1.1.1. Using max timestamp, get documents that were transferred AND deleted 5/14 */

DECLARE @ID_Rechnung int ,
    @XMLData xml;
DECLARE @Hist_ID1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Ext1 VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @CommandOUT1 NVARCHAR(4000)  

SELECT
    @XMLData =  xmldat.xmldataCol 
FROM
(
SELECT (
       SELECT
            -- HIER XML Daten generieren
            [InvoiceHeader].[InvoiceDate]            AS 'invoice-date',
            ([InvoiceHeader].[InvoiceNumber])                           AS 'invoice-number',
       cast(replace([InvoiceHeader].[GrossValue],' ','') as decimal(18,2))                           AS 'gross-total',
        cast(replace([InvoiceHeader].[NetValue],' ','') as decimal(18,2))                           AS 'amount-due',
        [InvoiceHeader].[VatRate]                           AS 'tax-rate',
        cast(replace([InvoiceHeader].[VatValue],' ','') as decimal(18,2))                           AS 'tax-amount',
  
        [ImagePath] AS 'image-scan-url',
        [InvoiceType] AS 'document-type',
        [LegalEntityVATNo] AS  'account-type/id',
        [LegalEntityName] AS  'account-type/name',
        [SupplierCode] as 'supplier/number',
        [Currency] as 'currency/code',   

    (
        SELECT rtrim([InvoiceLines].[LineNumber]) AS [order-line-num]
            , [PONumber] as [po-number],
            CAST([InvoiceLines].[UnitPrice] AS decimal(18,2)) AS Price ,
            [Quantity] as quantity,
            [TaxAmount] as [tax-amount],
            [LineTotal] as [total],
            [Decsription] as description


        FROM INTELLECTION.dbo.[InvoiceLines] WHERE INTELLECTION.dbo.[InvoiceLines].[DOCID] = @DOCID99
        FOR XML PATH('invoice-lines'), ROOT('invoice-line'), TYPE
    )
FROM INTELLECTION.dbo.[InvoiceHeader] 
WHERE INTELLECTION.dbo.[InvoiceHeader].[DOCID]  = @DOCID99
FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('invoice-header'), TYPE

--, TYPE, ROOT('invoice-header')

) AS xmldataCol
) AS xmldat;

SELECT  @XMLData
.query('<invoice-header>




{
   for $x in /invoice-header/*[local-name()!="root"]
   return $x,
     for $x in /invoice-header/root/r
     return <invoice-lines>/<invoice-line>{$x/*}</invoice-line></invoice-lines>
}
</invoice-header>') ;



 

END



GO
```

In my other code I use the following to call the SP:

```
DECLARE @CommandOUT1 NVARCHAR(4000)  
DECLARE @filenameDocID NVARCHAR(10)

SET @filenameDocID = '111'
       SET @CommandOUT1 = '
    bcp "exec INTELLECTION.[dbo].[XML_OUTVaribale] @DOCID99 = '+@filenameDocID+'" queryout "D:\New folder\' + @filenameDocID+'.xml" -S INTEL-SQL01\OUTSOURCECAPTURE -T -w -t' 

  print @CommandOUT1

     EXEC xp_cmdshell   @CommandOUT1
```

Here is code to generate the sample data:

```
USE [INTELLECTION]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[InvoiceLines]    Script Date: 2021/08/31 3:03:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceLines](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DOCID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PONumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Quantity] [numeric](18, 6) NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LineTotal] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LineNumber] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [TaxAmount] [numeric](18, 6) NULL,
    [Decsription] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceLines] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [INTELLECTION]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[InvoiceHeader]    Script Date: 2021/08/31 3:02:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceHeader](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DOCID] [int] NULL,
    [CorporateGroupID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Ready_Export] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [Rule_Match] [nchar](20) NULL,
    [PONumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [InvoiceType] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [InvoiceDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [NetValue] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [VatRate] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [VatValue] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DeliveryCost] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [GrossValue] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Supplier_address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Supplier_VATREG] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [VATCompInd] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [TaxInvoiceInd] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LegalEntityName] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [LegalEntityVATNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [LegalEntity_Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Currency] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [VatReg] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DeliveryNote] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [BankAccount] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Tin] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Images] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [Image] [image] NULL,
    [ImagePath] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [ImageName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [SupplierName] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [SupplierCode] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ReceiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TransferDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsProcessed] [int] NULL,
    [ProcessedDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceHeader] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__InvoiceHe__Trans__5070F446]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [TransferDate]
GO
```

Then the values for the tables

```
delete from [InvoiceHeader]
Delete from [InvoiceLines]



--1--------------------------------------------------
  INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency]
   )
values(
'1234'
, '20180509'
,'INV23455'
,'4100000169'
,'480.07'
,'417.45'
,'15%'
,'62.62'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR'
)



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '1234'
      ,'4100000169'
      ,'1.0'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'417.45'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

---2-----------------------------------------------------------------
      
  INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency])
values(
'451'
, '20180509'
,'VNH4125365'
,'4100000171'
,'11500.00'
,'10000.00'
,'15%'
,'1500.00'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR')



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '451'
      ,'4100000171'
      ,'0.5'
      ,'10000.00'
      ,'5000.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

      insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '451'
      ,'4100000171'
      ,'0.5'
      ,'10000.00'
      ,'5000.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

      ----Possible match2-----------------------------------------------

        INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency])
values(
'111'
, '20180509'
,'VNH4125365'
,'4100000170'
,'2794.50'
,'2430.00'
,'15%'
,'364.50'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR')



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '111'
      ,'4100000170'
      ,'9.00'
      ,'100.00'
      ,'900.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

      insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '111'
      ,'4100000170'
      ,'10.00'
      ,'153.00'
      ,'1530.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')
---4--------------------------------------------------------

  INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency])
values(
'222'
, '20180509'
,'WSDF4125365'
,'4100000159'
,'144020.25'
,'125235.00'
,'15%'
,'18785.25'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR')



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '222'
      ,'4100000159'
      ,'100.0'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'41745.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')
      insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '222'
      ,'4100000159'
      ,'200.00'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'83490.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')
-----5----------------------------------------------------
  INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency])
values(
'4444'
, '20180509'
,'DFVX4125365'
,'4100000179'
,'10380.99'
,'9026.95'
,'15%'
,'1354.04'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR')



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '4444'
      ,'4100000179'
      ,'10.00'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'4174.50'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

      insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '4444'
      ,'4100000179'
      ,'10.00'
      ,'370.30'
      ,'3703.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal');

        insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '4444'
      ,'4100000179'
      ,'1.00'
      ,'992.45'
      ,'992.45'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

          insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '4444'
      ,'4100000179'
      ,'1.00'
      ,'157.00'
      ,'157.00'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')



      -----6----------------------------------------------------
  INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency])
values(
'47898'
, '20180509'
,'SSS12234'
,'4100000152'
,'4175.47'
,'3630.84'
,'15%'
,'544.63'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR')



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '47898'
      ,'4100000152'
      ,'3.0'
      ,'470.35'
      ,'1411.05'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

      insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '47898'
      ,'4100000152'
      ,'3.0'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'1252.35'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')

insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '47898'
      ,'4100000152'
      ,'3.0'
      ,'322.48'
      ,'967.44'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')


       INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency]
   )
values(
'999999'
, '20180509'
,'NO_PO_Returned'
,'4100000999'
,'480.07'
,'417.45'
,'15%'
,'62.62'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR'
)



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '999999'
      ,'4100000999'
      ,'1.0'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'417.45'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')


        INSERT into [InvoiceHeader]
  ([DOCID],
   [InvoiceDate] ,
   [InvoiceNumber],
   [PONumber],
   [GrossValue],
   [NetValue],
   [VatRate]   ,
   [VatValue],
   [ImagePath] ,
   [InvoiceType],
   [LegalEntityVATNo] ,
   [LegalEntityName] ,
   [SupplierCode] ,
   [Currency]
   )
values(
'333'
, '20180509'
,'NO_PO_Returned'
,'4100000999'
,'480.07'
,'417.45'
,'15%'
,'62.62'
,'\\SHAREPATH\Attachment\'
,'Invoice'
,'4520321520'
,'ENGEN PTY'
,'00021455'
,'ZAR'
)



insert into [InvoiceLines]([DOCID]
      ,[PONumber]
      ,[Quantity]
      ,[UnitPrice]
      ,[LineTotal]
      ,[LineNumber]
      ,[TaxAmount]
      ,[Decsription])
      Values(
      '333'
      ,'4100000999'
      ,'1.0'
      ,'417.45'
      ,'417.45'
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,'Legal')
```

If I look at the xml it looks fine to me. Not sure were the markup issue is. Please help.

[image]

Not sure how to add the xml file but here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I don't know what XML validator you're using, but I used the above and got data out for the parameter `111` and [xmlvalidation.com](https://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0) said it was valid. YOu haven't included the actual XML you have, so we can't tell you why they isn't valid.

Comment: I also used xmlvalidation.com. I added the error in my post.

Comment: What are those 2 unicode unknown characters doing there, prior to `<invoice-header>`?

Comment: I have no idea. XML in SQL is new to me. Can the issue not be in my bcp queryout?

Comment: I tested now with xmlvalidation.com but only the result of my SP and no errors. Seems that the file that is created with bcp queryout is the issue

Comment: Honestly, I dislike the idea of using SQL Server to call `xp_cmdshell` to call `bcp`, @JCW . There are *better* ways to extract your data using a pull method; not SQL Server using a somewhat fake "push" method.

Comment: @Larnu is there anyway of fixing my code to do it in SQL Server? If there is no way of doing it, what would be the simplest way of doing it?

Comment: My guess is that the two blobs before the XML declaration represent a byte order mark. I don't know enough about your environment to know why the BOM is there or why it isn't accepted, but it's a common cause of this kind of trouble.